# Put time format in a Xamarin Forms input

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How about I would like to know how I can put a type of time format in an entry example 12:00 that when filling it there are the colons: that separate the hours from the minutes

I looked at some type of masks for the entrance but none adapted to what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are able to use the Xamarin [CommunityToolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/), you could use a [MaskedBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/maskedbehavior). In your case it would be something like this:

```xml
<Entry>
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <xct:MaskedBehavior 
            Mask="xx:xx" 
            UnMaskedCharacter="x"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend it worked very well